# Casting a struct onto variable length buffer

Tags: c, struct

Is it possible to create struct that I can cast to a buffer of variable size? For example if I have some data that looks something like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                       |
/                       /
/          DATA         /
|                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|          NAME         |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|          TIME         |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|          ETC          |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Would it be possible to have a struct similar to this

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t data[];
    uint8_t name;
    uint8_t time;
    uint8_t etc;
}Struct;
```

and then resize Struct.data at runtime to I can cast the structure directly onto the buffer?

I know I could just make a struct that uses pointers and have them point to parts of the buffer, but I was curious if this is possible because it would simplify my code and make it easier to read/use.

Comment: Not for `data`, unless it has a hard-coded length.

Comment: Although you could if `data` was last

Comment: I believe this would work if `data` was at the end of the structure.

Comment: Move `data[]` to the end and lookup [flexible arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to do the following:

```c
typedef struct {
   uint8_t name;
   uint8_t time;
   uint8_t etc;
} Struct;

char *buf = ...;

Struct *s = (Struct*)(buf + data_len);

... s->name ...
```

There are two problems with this.

1. Alignment. You can't just place a structure at any address you want on every machine, so the concept is fundamentally flawed unless you're targeting a specific machine as well.
2. Padding. The compiler is free to place padding between the fields of the structure, so the concept is fundamentally flawed unless you're targeting a specific compiler and tell that compiler to not use any padding.

In short, take a different approach.

```c
typedef struct {
   uint8_t name;
   uint8_t time;
   uint8_t etc;
} Struct;

char *buf = ...;
buf += data_len;

Struct s;
memcpy(&s.name, buf, sizeof(s.name));  buf += sizeof(s.name);
memcpy(&s.time, buf, sizeof(s.time));  buf += sizeof(s.time);
memcpy(&s.etc,  buf, sizeof(s.etc));   buf += sizeof(s.etc);

... s.name ...
```

Checking to make sure you don't read beyond the end of `buf` is left to you.

Comment: Yep! That is pretty much what I was hoping to do, except `Struct *s = (Struct*)buf`. It's too bad that it isn't possible, it isn't a big deal but I was curious

Comment: Well, it is, with the caveats I mentioned. `gcc` on an x86 or x64 could do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can move the variable length buffer to the end of the structure, and you don't care about portability, you can do this. This example relies on `#pragma pack` to align fields on 8 byte boundaries.

**variable_length.h**

```c
#ifndef VARIABLE_LENGTH_H
#define VARIABLE_LENGTH_H

#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(8)

typedef struct {
    uint8_t name;
    uint8_t time;
    uint8_t etc;
    size_t size;
} header_t;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t name;
    uint8_t time;
    uint8_t etc;
    size_t size;
    uint8_t data[];
} data_t;

#pragma pack()

#endif
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "variable_length.h"

header_t *create_buffer(char *buffer_name) {
    size_t buffer_size = strlen(buffer_name) + 1;
    size_t size = sizeof(header_t) + buffer_size;
    data_t *result = calloc(1, size);
    if (NULL == result) {
        perror("Could not allocate memory for buffer");
        exit(1);
    }
    result->name = 'A';
    result->time = 1;
    result->etc = 'x';
    result->size = buffer_size;
    strncpy((char *) result->data, buffer_name, buffer_size);
    return (header_t *) result;
}

int main(void) {
    header_t *result = create_buffer("example buffer");
    data_t *example = (data_t *) result;
    printf("name = %c\n", example->name);
    printf("time = %d\n", example->time);
    printf("etc  = %c\n", example->etc);
    printf("size = %lu\n", example->size);
    for (int index = 0; index < example->size; index++) {
        printf("%c", example->data[index]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("address of name = %p\n", &example->name);
    printf("address of time = %p\n", &example->time);
    printf("address of etc  = %p\n", &example->etc);
    printf("address of size = %p\n", &example->size);
    printf("address of data = %p\n", example->data);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
name = A
time = 1
etc  = x
size = 15
example buffer

address of name = 0xf20260
address of time = 0xf20261
address of etc  = 0xf20262
address of size = 0xf20268
address of data = 0xf20270
```

**Notes**

As you can see, the address of `size` is 8 more than the address of `name`, and the address of `data` is 8 more than the address of `size`. If your target is a 32-bit architecture, you could use `#pragma pack(4)`.

**Warning**

If you are trying to access addresses that are not on machine word boundaries, this might generate very slow code on x86 and x64 architectures, and code that crashes with `SIGBUS` on RISC architectures.

**Trivia**

I first saw structure definitions like this in Microsoft driver code.